# Hide columns of property page in vb6

Tags: forms, listview, properties, vb6, hide

I tried below code to hide column of property page in vb6.

```
List1.CoulmnHeaders(8).Width = 0
```

Initially the column is not visible but when you drag or resize the column header it appears. How to prevent user from not displaying those values.

Comment: Is List1 a ListView control?  If so, the only way I know to do what you need is to subclass the control.

Comment: What's the purpose of hiding that column? Mabye there are other ways to achieve the same w/o the need to hide it or the need for the column in the first place.